# Invalid Onionsite Address

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Most of the onion links that I copy paste in DuckDuckGo on tor browser show 'invalid onionsite address'. Even the very common ones like the url for torch. I tried connecting with a bridge, it didn't help. Now I don't have much idea at all about how it works, but I read an answer on quora related to my issue and it said to add this line in the torrc file- 'FascistFirewall 1', so I did.. still nothing.

I opened the DuckDuckGo onion search engine. Then I tried to paste the url for torch in there. Many clearnet search results came.. and above the results a pop up said 'You are trying to reach an onion/hidden service. To access cnkj6nippubgycuj.onion via web you will have to use Tor Browser.' But I am already searching all this from Tor browser itself.. I have connected to tor browser. So why does it say that, why doesn't the link open? This one onion chatroom that I have been accessing for a few days, it always opens no problem. It is an onion link too, so why don't other onion links open?

Comment: i dont know but if i did know i would syay cause i agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onion services with short urls are called "V2" addresses. For example, cnkj6nippubgycuj.onion is a V2 address. These addresses have been deprecated as of July of last year and you can't reach them anymore. Here is the [page](https://support.torproject.org/onionservices/v2-deprecation/) on the Tor Website talking about this.

Here's an example of a V3 address. This is to the [Tor Project's blog](http://pzhdfe7jraknpj2qgu5cz2u3i4deuyfwmonvzu5i3nyw4t4bmg7o5pad.onion).

Comment: Thank you. I read about the deprecation from your link. It says to make a few changes in the torrc file and few other modifications, so is that for the service operators only? Or do the users need to do that too. Or do I just have to find the new url for the site I am looking and paste that?

Comment: Just just need to find new urls. Nothing else with make a difference. Onion service operators need to update their torrc files to use the new V3 standard. Ubuntu/Debian are the worse when it comes to this because their default file is many years out of date.

Comment: Okay got it. Had been confused for days.