# Can't acces onion sites with some links

Tags: onion-services, facebook, onionaddress

So, im kind of new on this, I'm using Tor with Tails. I cannot acces to onion sites using links such as:
[facebookcorewwwi.onion] (Unable to connect Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at facebookcorewwwi.onion) wich i understand should work just fine, I only could acces when using this other link:
[facebookwkhpilnemxj7asaniu7vnjjbiltxjqhye3mhbshg7kx5tfyd.onion]
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid Onionsite Address](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/22988/invalid-onionsite-address)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to reach an obsoleted V2 hidden service - they're not working any more

Answer (score 1):

Tor doesn't support v2 addresses and only v3 onion addresses can be surfed through the tor browser. Using a deprecated version of tor doesn't work because v2 domain resolution for Hidden Services has been stopped on the tor network and only v3 domains are resolved for their particular services.

Answer (score 0):

The address `facebookcorewwwi.onion` (and similar addresses which have 16 characters plus an `.onion` address) are old addresses. This address format was called a version 2 Onion address or short v2 address. Those addresses are deprecated and will not work anymore.

Facebook has adopted to the new version 3 of Onion Services. Those have longer onion addresses. So you can reach Facebook only via `facebookwkhpilnemxj7asaniu7vnjjbiltxjqhye3mhbshg7kx5tfyd.onion`. If you want to know their actual onion address, you can go to https://www.facebook.com/onion-service. This site lists the address.

Furthermore Alec Muffett maintains a list of so-called [real world onion sites](https://github.com/alecmuffett/real-world-onion-sites#index). You'll find many more working addresses in his list.